# Can we copy text after a image from unicode file in Sikuli?

Tags: python-2.7, sikuli

I have a file content as below

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><cont:ContactId><all:Individual.partyId>10028305</all:Individual.partyId></cont:ContactId><all:applicationId>C18400</all:applicationId>
```

I need to copy "C18400" from this file and print in output in SIKULI. Please let me know whether we can use python script to fetch the output or is there any other way to do it. Also let me know whether we can use sikuli image capture for this, but this application id that I need in output is dynamic which keeps changing.

I used the below python script, but it didn't work

CODE:

```
with open("D:\\SODS.txt","r") as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if "applicationId" in line:
            print "true"
            print re.search(r"applicationId\>(.+?)\<",fp)
```

ERROR:

TypeError: expected str or unicode but got

Comment: What does this have to do with Sikuli? This looks like you just need to read an XML file in Python. Search for "Python XML" and pick an XML-parsing library.

Comment: @user3571567: I'm sure you know that Sikuli is based in mostly-Python, which is why Nathaniel Waisbrot suggested looking up Python XML. When you need any computational power, and you're not using the graphic-identifying components of Sikuli, regular Python will be the way to go.  That being said--what line is giving the error? What does your output look like (or do you get none at all?)

Answer (score 0):

Actually my file looks as below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <cont:CreateContactResponse xmlns:cont="http://DataModelContactManagement" xmlns:all="http://MID/Business/0.1/All" xmlns:com="http://SOA/1.0/Common">
     <com:status>0</com:status>
     <com:description/>
     <cont:ContactId>
        <all:MIDBusCm.Individual.partyId>10028310</all:MIDBusCm.Individual.partyId>
     </cont:ContactId>
     <all:MIDBusCu.CustomerOrder.applicationId>C18403</all:MIDBusCu.CustomerOrder.applicationId>
  </cont:CreateContactResponse>
```

I tried the below PYTHON script

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data = open("D:\\Pravina\\Projects\\Meteor\\Automation\\API\\SODS.txt", 'r')
tree = ET.parse(data)
doc = tree.getroot()
print doc

 rootText='.//{http://'SOA'/1.0/Common}'
 errorCode=tree.find(rootText + 'status').text
 print errorCode
```

With the above code the output i got was

"/schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope at a>
0 "

In my case the output should be "C18403" this is in between the tag 'all:MIDBusCu.CustomerOrder.applicationId'.

Please let me know if I am missing something here?